# I want to round values to different decimals places within the same column of R dataframe can it be done?

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
Analyte  Value     
Fe       60.3203 
Sio2     2.3003 
As       0.5564
```

I want to round the values column to different decimals places depending on its value.  That is if the value is > 1 then I want to show 2 decimal places, and if it is < 1 I want to round to 3 decimal places
Is it possible to apply this to an R dataframe?

I have tried:

```
df$value <- if_else(df$value >1.0, round(df$value, digits =3), round(df$value, digits =2))
```

and

```
df$value <- if_else(df$value >1.0, format(round(df$value, nsmall =3)), format(round(df$value, nsmall =2)))
```

I have also tried a few variations of the above two options but I  always end up with the whole column being rounded to the same number of decimal places.

I suspect this type of more suited for some sort of graphical type feature when presenting the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to control the decimal places if this is for display purpose :

```
with(df, ifelse(Value > 1, sprintf("%.3f",Value), sprintf("%.2f",Value)))
#[1] "60.320" "2.300"  "0.56"
```

---

You were close with `format` and `round`,  you can do :

```
with(df, trimws(ifelse(Value > 1, format(round(Value, 3), nsmall = 3), 
                                  format(round(Value, 2), nsmall = 2))))
```